# R: Differences by group and adding

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I would like to know how to do this operation simpler.
Imagine I have a data.frame like this one:

```
set.seed(1)
ID <- rep(1:3,each=4)
XX <- round(runif(12),3)
TT <- rep(1:4, 3)
ZZ <- ave(XX*TT,ID, FUN = cumsum)
DF <- data.frame(ID, XX,  ZZ)   

ID  TT   XX    ZZ
1    1   0.266 0.266
1    2   0.372 1.010
1    3   0.573 2.729
1    4   0.908 6.361
2    1   0.202 0.202
2    2   0.898 1.998
2    3   0.945 4.833
2    4   0.661 7.477
3    1   0.629 0.629
3    2   0.062 0.753
3    3   0.206 1.371
3    4   0.177 2.079
```

I' would like to get, for each column, the increments (differences between two consecutive elements) by groups of ID. Keeping the first one (as if there is a previous zero).

```
ID    TT      XX    ZZ
 1    1    0.266 0.266
 1    2    0.106 0.744
 1    3    0.201 1.719
 1    4    0.335 3.632
 2    1    0.202 0.202
 2    2    0.696 1.796
 2    3    0.047 2.835
 2    4   -0.284 2.644
 3    1    0.629 0.629
 3    2   -0.567 0.124
 3    3    0.144 0.618
 3    4   -0.029 0.708
```

I've tried with

```
ave(DF[3:4],DF$ID,FUN=function(x) diff(c(0,x)))
```

but it doesn't work, it produces the error:

```
 Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**Isn't there an easy way to do it?**
I've found that I can get the proper output with:

```
ave(DF[3:4],DF$ID,FUN=function(x) 
  sapply(x, FUN=function(y) diff(c(0,y))))
```

but it gets quite long and complex for a so simple operation.
I've found that I can also do it by using data.table    but I prefer to be able to do it with base R.

```
setDT(DF)
DF[, lapply(.SD, FUN=function(x) diff(c(0,x)) ), keyby = ID ]
```

I also don't know how to **insert a new row** (plenty of zeroes) **at the beginning of each group** or given some condition.

```
ID   XX    ZZ
1     0     0
1 0.266 0.266
1 0.372 1.010
1 0.573 2.729
1 0.908 6.361
2     0     0
2 0.202 0.202
2 0.898 1.998
2 0.945 4.833
2 0.661 7.477
3     0     0
3 0.629 0.629
3 0.062 0.753
3 0.206 1.371
3 0.177 2.079
```

I've tried with:

```
ave(DF[3:4],DF$ID,FUN=function(x) sapply(x, FUN=function(y) (c(0,y))))
```

warning:

```
data length [10] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of
rows [4]
```

I guess the general way to do it would be working with indexes of the rows.

PD:  I've updated the post.

Trying to do it simpler I had removed the TT column but I have leater noticed that is important.

My solution assumes that the table is ordered by TT, but sometimes it's not like that.
What I really want is:

```
XX1
XX2-XX1
XX3-XX2
XX4-XX3
```

Where we get the subindexes not from the position on the table but from T.
I don't know whether is more effcicient to do it by first sorting the columns by TT  or  by creating a paste() syntax.

Comment: `> ZZ <- ave(XX*TT,ID, FUN = cumsum)` results in "Error in split(x, g) : object 'TT' not found".

Comment: Yes, I missed it. Just updated. But it's just an example.

Comment: Guys, what about a simple solution for my second question? Adding  a row at the beginning of each group or at a given position.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to include two separate questions in one post. If any of the posts below answered your first question, I would remove the second question from this post entirely, and post it as a separate question. Then choose the "best" answer below. I've seen similar questions to the one you pose as your second question, so it may be worth a search prior to posting it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to use `lapply()` across the relevant columns, as `ave()` will not take a list in its first argument.  Try this:

```
df[-1] <- lapply(
    df[-1], 
    function(x) ave(x, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(x[1], diff(x)))
)
```

which gives the updated `df`

> ```
>    ID     XX    ZZ
> 1   1  0.266 0.266
> 2   1  0.106 0.744
> 3   1  0.201 1.719
> 4   1  0.335 3.632
> 5   2  0.202 0.202
> 6   2  0.696 1.796
> 7   2  0.047 2.835
> 8   2 -0.284 2.644
> 9   3  0.629 0.629
> 10  3 -0.567 0.124
> 11  3  0.144 0.618
> 12  3 -0.029 0.708
> ```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), XX = c(0.266, 0.372, 0.573, 0.908, 0.202, 0.898, 0.945, 
0.661, 0.629, 0.062, 0.206, 0.177), ZZ = c(0.266, 1.01, 2.729, 
6.361, 0.202, 1.998, 4.833, 7.477, 0.629, 0.753, 1.371, 2.079
)), .Names = c("ID", "XX", "ZZ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it in a `data.table`

```
set.seed(1)
ID <- rep(1:3, each=4)
XX <- round(runif(12), 3)
##ZZ <- ave(XX*TT,ID, FUN = cumsum) #we don't have TT
DF <- data.table(ID, XX)

DF[,XX_dif:=XX-c(0,head(XX,length(XX)-1)),by=ID]
# or alternatively using shift()
# DF[, XX_dif := XX-shift(XX, fill=0L), by=ID]

    ID    XX XX_dif
 1:  1 0.266  0.266
 2:  1 0.372  0.106
 3:  1 0.573  0.201
 4:  1 0.908  0.335
 5:  2 0.202  0.202
 6:  2 0.898  0.696
 7:  2 0.945  0.047
 8:  2 0.661 -0.284
 9:  3 0.629  0.629
10:  3 0.062 -0.567
11:  3 0.206  0.144
12:  3 0.177 -0.029
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(ZZ = c(ZZ[1], diff(ZZ)))
#      ID    XX    ZZ
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      1 0.266 0.266
#2      1 0.372 0.744
#3      1 0.573 1.719
#4      1 0.908 3.632
#5      2 0.202 0.202
#6      2 0.898 1.796
#7      2 0.945 2.835
#8      2 0.661 2.644
#9      3 0.629 0.629
#10     3 0.062 0.124
#11     3 0.206 0.618
#12     3 0.177 0.708
```