# dplyr function returning false NAs

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, time-series

I have the same question as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706633/dplyr-lag-function-returns-nas), but the question remains unanswered and I also am having the same problem.

I have attached a sample of my data [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

The version of R that I am using is 3.4.2 and the version of dplyr is 0.7.4.

To get everyone up to speed...
After importing the data, I do these edits:

```
#specify which species are predators (pp = 1) and prey (pp = 0)
d1 = d1 %>%
    group_by(sps) %>% #grouped by species
    mutate(pp=ifelse(sps %in% c("MUXX", "MUVI","MEME"), 1,0)) #mutate to specify predators as 1 and prey as 0

d1$datetime=strftime(paste(d1$date,d1$time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',usetz=FALSE) #converting the date/time into a new format 

head(d1) #visualize the first few lines of the data

d2 = d1 %>% filter(km %in% c("80")) #restricting the observations to just one location (km 80)
```

Now for where the problems arise (the NAs):

```
d2 = d2 %>% mutate(prev = dplyr::lag(pp)) 
#when I look at the output I see the lag function isn't working (shown below)

> d2
# A tibble: 209 x 10
# Groups:   sps [10]
  ID       date    km culv.id   type    sps   time    pp         datetime  prev
<int>     <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>            <chr> <dbl>
1     1 2012-06-19    80       A    DCC  MICRO   2:19     0 2012-06-19 02:19    NA
2     2 2012-06-21    80       A    DCC   MUXX  23:23     1 2012-06-21 23:23    NA
3     3 2012-07-15    80       A    DCC   MAMO  11:38     0 2012-07-15 11:38    NA
4     4 2012-07-20    80       A    DCC  MICRO  22:19     0 2012-07-20 22:19     0
5     5 2012-07-29    80       A    DCC  MICRO  23:03     0 2012-07-29 23:03     0
6     8 2012-08-07    80       A    DCC   PRLO   2:04     0 2012-08-07 02:04    NA
7     9 2012-08-08    80       A    DCC  MICRO  23:56     0 2012-08-08 23:56     0
8    10 2012-08-09    80       A    DCC   PRLO  23:06     0 2012-08-09 23:06     0
9    11 2012-08-13    80       A    DCC  MICRO   0:04     0 2012-08-13 00:04     0
10   12 2012-08-13    80       A    DCC  MICRO   0:46     0 2012-08-13 00:46     0
```

Might anyone have any suggests for why the lag function isn't working?

Comment: `d2 <-  d2 %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(prev = dplyr::lag(pp))`

Comment: @Mako212 That instantly fixed my problem! Thank you!!! 
If possible, could you explain to me what you noticed happening in my output so that I can solve this problem for myself if it ever comes up again?

Comment: Added my comment as an answer with more detail.

Comment: Made one final note about what's actually happening with the NAs, you may actually not want to `ungroup()` because `lag()` is working correctly on the grouped data frame, if you want the lagged value by group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In one of your previous operations, you specified `group_by(sps)`, that group will stay attached to your data frame until you `ungroup()`. Some row level operations won't be affected by the group, but aggregate functions, and functions that evaluate based on values from more than one row will.

```
d2 <- d2 %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(prev = dplyr::lag(pp))
```

Also, as to what I noticed:

1. I saw in your header `# Groups:   sps [10]`
2. The first instance of each `sps` value is NA, but the second instance of each is correctly 0

As a final edit however, the first value of `lag()` will always be NA, because there is no previous value. This is also true with `group_by(sps)`, however it means you'll have 10 NA values, one for the first instance of each factor level. If you want the lagged value within the group, then you should not `ungroup()` and the function is working properly creating those NAs. You may replace those NAs with 0, or another value if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. When I specify `ungroup()` as you indicated before the `mutate()` function, can I then `group_by(sps)` again afterwards? Or might that cause problems?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist you absolutely can, the group only effects calculations where it's in place, so if you ungroup, you can perform as many ungrouped operations as you like, until you group again.